# Applicative: Prove `pure f <*> x = pure (flip ($)) <*> x <*> pure f`

Tags: haskell, applicative, category-theory

During my study of [Typoclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia) I encountered this proof, but I'm not sure if my proof is correct. The question is:

> One might imagine a variant of the interchange law that says something about applying a pure function to an effectful argument. Using the above laws, prove that:
>
> `pure f <*> x = pure (flip ($)) <*> x <*> pure f`

Where "above laws" points to [Applicative Laws](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia#Laws_2), briefly:

```
pure id <*> v = v -- identity law
pure f <*> pure x = pure (f x) -- homomorphism
u <*> pure y = pure ($ y) <*> u -- interchange
u <*> (v <*> w) = pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w -- composition
```

My proof is as follows:

```
pure f <*> x = pure (($) f) <*> x -- identical
pure f <*> x = pure ($) <*> pure f <*> x -- homomorphism
pure f <*> x = pure (flip ($)) <*> x <*> pure f -- flip arguments
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up proving it backwards:

```
pure (flip ($)) <*> x <*> pure f
    = (pure (flip ($)) <*> x) <*> pure f -- <*> is left-associative
    = pure ($ f) <*> (pure (flip ($)) <*> x) -- interchange
    = pure (.) <*> pure ($ f) <*> pure (flip ($)) <*> x -- composition
    = pure (($ f) . (flip ($))) <*> x -- homomorphism
    = pure (flip ($) f . flip ($)) <*> x -- identical
    = pure f <*> x
```

Explanation of the last transformation:

`flip ($)` has type `a -> (a -> c) -> c`, intuitively, it first takes an argument of type `a`, then a function that accepts that argument, and in the end it calls the function with the first argument. So `flip ($) 5` takes as argument a function which gets called with `5` as it's argument. If we pass `(+ 2)` to `flip ($) 5`, we get `flip ($) 5 (+2)` which is equivalent to the expression `(+2) $ 5`, evaluating to `7`.

`flip ($) f` is equivalent to `\x -> x $ f`, that means, it takes as input a function and calls it with the function `f` as argument.

The composition of these functions works like this: First `flip ($)` takes `x` as it's first argument, and returns a function `flip ($) x`, this function is awaiting a function as it's last argument, which will be called with `x` as it's argument. Now this function `flip ($) x` is passed to `flip ($) f`, or to write it's equivalent `(\x -> x $ f) (flip ($) x)`, this results in the expression `(flip ($) x) f`, which is equivalent to `f $ x`.

You can check the type of `flip ($) f . flip ($)` is something like this (depending on your function `f`):

```
λ: let f = sqrt
λ: :t (flip ($) f) . (flip ($))
(flip ($) f) . (flip ($)) :: Floating c => c -> c
```

Comment: That last step is straightforward enough with a single eta-expansion, isn't it? `($f) . flip ($) ≡ \x -> ($f) $ ($x) ≡ \x -> ($x)$f ≡ \x -> f $ x ≡ f`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yeah, it should be, I'm actually writing a post on Typoclassopedia with solutions to the exercises, and this explanation is for that post, so I tried to explain piece by piece for anyone struggling to grasp it at first.
btw, thanks for the edit, looks much better.

Answer (score 3):

The first two steps of your proof look fine, but the last step doesn't.  While the definition of `flip` allows you to use a law like:

```
f a b = flip f b a
```

that doesn't mean:

```
pure f <*> a <*> b = pure (flip f) <*> b <*> a
```

In fact, this is false in general.  Compare the output of these two lines:

```
pure (+) <*> [1,2,3] <*> [4,5]
pure (flip (+)) <*> [4,5] <*> [1,2,3]
```

If you want a hint, you are going to need to use the original interchange law at some point to prove this variant.

In fact, I found I had to use the homomorphism, interchange, and composition laws to prove this, and part of the proof was pretty tricky, especially getting the sections right --like `($ f)`, which is different from `(($) f)`.  It was helpful to have GHCi open to double-check that each step of my proof type checked and gave the right result.  (Your proof above type checks fine; it's just that the last step wasn't justified.)

```
> let f = sqrt
> let x = [1,4,9]
> pure f <*> x
[1.0,2.0,3.0]
> pure (flip ($)) <*> x <*> pure f
[1.0,2.0,3.0]
>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I ended up proving it backwards by going from the right-hand side to the left-hand side. I didn't accept your answer as it doesn't really include the proof, care to share your proof?

Comment: My proof was the same backwards proof as yours, with a few extra steps at the end similar to @leftroundabout's eta expansion.  Feel free to accept your own answer as the complete one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd remark that such theorems are, as a rule, a lot less involved when written in mathematical style of a *monoidal functor*, rather than the applicative version, i.e. with the equivalent class

```
class Functor f => Monoidal f where
  pure :: a -> f a
  (⑂) :: f a -> f b -> f (a,b)
```

Then the laws are

```
id <$> v = v
f <$> (g <$> v) = f . g <$> v
f <$> pure x = pure (f x)
x ⑂ pure y = fmap (,y) x
a⑂(b⑂c) = assoc <$> (a⑂b)⑂c
```

where `assoc ((x,y),z) = (x,(y,z))`.

The theorem then reads

```
pure u ⑂ x = swap <$> x ⑂ pure u
```

Proof:

```
swap <$> x ⑂ pure u
    = swap <$> fmap (,u) x
    = swap . (,u) <$> x
    = (u,) <$> x
    = pure u ⑂ x
```

□